# SVN to git migration: How to add branches from SVN to migrated git (Gerrit)

Tags: git, svn, migration, gerrit, svn2git

I have already migrated a SVN repo to git and added it to a Gerrit project.

My problem is that the SVN repo has multiple branches. How to do I migrate the branches and add them to an existing Gerrit project?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://blog.jessitron.com/2013/08/converting-from-svn-to-git.html

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" refs/remotes/svn |
   sed 's#svn/##' | grep -v '^tags' |
      while read aBranch; do git branch $aBranch svn/$aBranch || exit 1; done
```